# with jest, how do I mock an fs.readdirSync call withFileTypes using filter and map

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking

In Jest, how would I mock this `fs.readdirSync` in this function.

```
export const getDirectoryFiles = async (directory) => {
  return fs
  .readdirSync(directory, { withFileTypes: true })
  .filter(dirent => !dirent.isDirectory())
  .map(dirent => dirent.name);
}
```

When I do a

```
const fsMock = jest.spyOn(fs, 'readdirSync');
```

I set up the `Dirent` as

```js
const { Dirent, constants } = jest.requireActual('fs');
const directory = new Dirent('directory', constants.UV_DIRENT_DIR);
```

And call

```
fsMock.mockResolvedValue([directory]);
```

When I call expect on the function that uses readdirSync, it errors out with.

> TypeError: fs.readdirSync(...).filter is not a function

So I don't know to resolve this.

I want to put 2 file names in at some point to just test it will come back with those names.

I found "Dirent" code for an example, but don't know if that is correct.

```
  it('getDirectoryFiles', async () => {
    const { Dirent, constants } = jest.requireActual('fs');

    // Prepare our mock
    const directory = new Dirent('directory', constants.UV_DIRENT_DIR);
    const fsMock = jest.spyOn(fs, 'readdirSync');

    fsMock.mockResolvedValue([directory]);

    // expect.assertions(1);
    const files = await getDirectoryFiles("/dir/stuff");

    // quick test
    expect(files).not.toBeNull;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

- No need to use `jest.requireActual('fs')` since you don't mock `fs` module.
- `fs.readdirSync()` is synchronization method, use [`mockReturnValue()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnvaluevalue) rather than `mockResolvedValue()`.

```
import fs from 'fs';

export const getDirectoryFiles = async (directory) => {
    return fs
        .readdirSync(directory, { withFileTypes: true })
        .filter((dirent) => !dirent.isDirectory())
        .map((dirent) => dirent.name);
};
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import fs, { Dirent, constants } from 'fs';
import { getDirectoryFiles } from './';

describe('76733429', () => {
    test('should pass', async () => {
        const directory = new Dirent('directory', constants.UV_DIRENT_DIR);
        const fsMock = jest.spyOn(fs, 'readdirSync');
        fsMock.mockReturnValue([directory]);
        const files = await getDirectoryFiles('/dir/stuff');
        expect(files).not.toBeNull;
        fsMock.mockRestore();
    });
});
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
    testEnvironment: 'node'
};
```